# How to properly read in a "maze.txt" file in Java

Tags: java, recursion, bufferedreader, filereader, traversal

For my homework assignment we are to traverse a virtual maze using recursion. I am wanting to make sure I am reading in the file properly. The goal of my code at this point is to read in a text file containing the maze and place an 'X' at the starting point of the maze.

Additionally, I read on another SO post about using BufferedReader with FileReader but the post was kind of vague - what is advantage of that?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class ReadInMaze 
{
private static char[][] maze = null;
private static int rows = 0;
private static int cols = 0;
private static int xStart = 0;
private static int yStart = 0;

public static void Maze(File mazeFile) throws IOException
{
    File mazeFile = new File ("C:/Users/Mark/workspace/18-20_MazeTraversal_Hard/src/MazeForMazeTraversalHW.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mazeFile));

    Scanner lineOfFile = new Scanner(reader.readLine());

    rows = lineOfFile.nextInt(); //get the number of rows of the maze
    cols = lineOfFile.nextInt(); // get the number of columns of the maze
    maze = new char[rows][cols]; //create a char array of the proper size

    //For loops to iterate the rows and col to find the start/enterance of the maze as it pertains to the first char in the row
    for (int y = 0; y < cols; y ++)
    {
        lineOfFile = new Scanner(reader.readLine());
        for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
        {
            char start = lineOfFile.next().charAt(0);
            maze[x][y] = start;

            //statement to set the starting coorinates for the maze
            if (start == '.')
            {
                xStart = x;
                yStart = y;
            }

        }
    }


}
```

The maze from my text file looks like this:

```
# # # # # # # # # # # #
# . . . # . . . . . . #
. . # . # . # # # # . #
# # # . # . . . . # . #
# . . . . # # # . # . .
# # # # . # . # . # . #
# . . # . # . # . # . #
# # . # . # . # . # . #
# . . . . . . . . # . #
# # # # # # . # # # . #
# . . . . . . # . . . #
# # # # # # # # # # # #
```

Comment: As it is now, you're looking at *every* character in the maze from the top left to the bottom right, and saving each period character's position as the start. This will give you the period closest to the bottom and right. 

Think about which rows and columns you need to look in to find the entrance to the maze.

Comment: how do you know where to start? from the left or the right starting point?

Comment: isn't my starting point [0][0] ? where x = 0 and y = 0 in the nested for loops. Would that place my starting point at the top left of the grid?

Comment: yeah that's the top left, but how you have it the last '.' that goes through the double for loop will be set to the starting point of the right '.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something like this for one of my classes here is how I read in the maze, I used a filechooser so you should replace that with your file name, then once you have the maze you can manipulate it as you please

```
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chooser.getSelectedFile()));
                        String rea = read.readLine();
                        String[] split = rea.split(" ");
                        width =  Integer.valueOf(split[0]);
                        height = Integer.valueOf(split[1]);

                        String readline;
                        int num = 0;
                        maze1 = new char[width][height];
                        while((readline = read.readLine()) != null){
                            char[] ch = readline.toCharArray();
                            for(int i = 0;i < ch.length;i++){
                                maze1[i][num] = ch[i];
                            }
                            num++;
                        }
```

that is assuming your maze is formatted like this with the width and the height at the top of the maze file separated with a space

```
12 12
# # # # # # # # # # # #
# . . . # . . . . . . #
. . # . # . # # # # . #
# # # . # . . . . # . #
# . . . . # # # . # . .
# # # # . # . # . # . #
# . . # . # . # . # . #
# # . # . # . # . # . #
# . . . . . . . . # . #
# # # # # # . # # # . #
# . . . . . . # . . . #
# # # # # # # # # # # #
```